# Replace slice of a numpy array with values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert

Say I've got two numpy arrays which were created this way:

```
zeros = np.zeros((270,270))
ones = np.ones((150,150))
```

How can I insert `ones` in `zeros` at position `[60,60]`?
I want an array that looks like a "square in the square".

I've tried the following two options:

```
np.put(empty, [60,60], ones)
np.put(empty, [3541], ones)
np.put[empty, [60:210,60:210], ones)
```

but the latter yields invalid syntax and the first two don't work either. Has anyone got an idea how this could work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way you can replace values in zeros with ones.

```
zeros[60:210,60:210] = ones
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes things can be straightforward, too ;-)

Comment: Does this still work?